# Apache Reverse Proxy redirect with assets folder in another path

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm using Apache2 to perform Reverse Proxy for my tomcat.

my domain name is https://dev.domain.com to be redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp

proxy is ok but tomcat is having an asset folder located in the root folder (http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets)

while loading my dev.domain.com page I have a 404 Error for every assets elements to be displayed.
Here is my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    proxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine on

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName dev.domain.com

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/

    SSLCertificateFile ....

</VirtualHost>
```

it seems that everything which is not in the MyApp folder is not correctly redirected, do you know I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/
```

Is making all requests to '/' proxied to 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/'. This means that requesting '/assets' will translate to 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/assets'.
I think you have two choices:

- either move 'assets' directory inside 'MyApp'
- or add a separate ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse for 'assets' directory

  ```
  ProxyPass /assets/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/
  ProxyPassReverse /assets/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/
  ```

Comment: by adding ProxyPass /assets/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/
ProxyPassReverse /assets/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/ first in the conf file it works perfectly, thanks Julien